# Storing multple arrays in a database rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, database, sqlite

I'm pulling data from the UCAS website and storing it in a series of arrays as can be seen below. I want to store these arrays in a database but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Can anyone help? Ideally in sqlite3 although I plan on changing this to postgres at a later date.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController


require 'mechanize'

class Scraper



    def process_unis
        @mechanize = Mechanize.new

        @unis_array = []
        page_num = 1
        next_page_link = true
        # Load initial search page
        @page = @mechanize.get('http://search.ucas.com/search/providers?CountryCode=3&RegionCode=&Lat=&Lng=&Feather=&Vac=2&Query=&ProviderQuery=&AcpId=&Location=scotland&IsFeatherProcessed=True&SubjectCode=&AvailableIn=2016')
        while  next_page_link
            puts "- Scraping uni page: #{page_num}" 
            # Loops through all unis on page
            @page.search('li.result').each do |uni|
                # Sets hash to store all uni data
                uni_info = {}
                uni_name = uni.search('h3').text
                uni_info[:name] = uni_name
                uni_more_courses_link = uni.search('.morecourseslink a').first
                if uni_more_courses_link
                    # If there is a link to a courses page for the uni go to that
                    uni_info[:courses] = process_courses_page(@mechanize.get(uni_more_courses_link["href"])) 
                else
                    # Otherwise process all the courses on the current page for that uni
                    uni_info[:courses] = process_inline_courses(uni)
                end
                # Add complete uni info to array. This may also be a good place to inset the uni in the database
                @unis_array.push(uni_info)
            end
            # Checks if there is a next page and navigates if so
            next_page_link = @page.search('.pager a[text()=">"]').first
            if(next_page_link) 
                @page = @mechanize.get(next_page_link["href"])
                page_num += 1
            end
        end
    end

    # Just a function to print what has been added. Can be removed if unneeded
    def print_course_info(course_info)
        puts "--- Adding course: #{course_info[:name]}" 
        puts "---- Duration: #{course_info[:duration]}"
        puts "---- Qualification: #{course_info[:qualification]}"

    end



    def print_details_info(details_info)

        puts "---- link: #{details_info[:url]}"

    end


    def print_entry_info(entry_info)

        puts "---- Requirements: #{entry_info[:req]}"
        puts ""
    end 


    # Removes excess spaces and new line characters from duration and qual text
    def clean_text(text)
        return text.gsub!('  ', '').gsub!("\n", '').gsub!("\r", '')
    end

    def clean_reqs(text)
        return text.gsub!('  ', '').gsub!("\n", '').gsub!("\r", '')
    end



    def process_inline_courses(uni)
        uni_name = uni.search('h3').text
        puts "-- Scraping #{uni_name} courses"
        courses_array = []

        # Loops through all courses, saves their info into a hash and pushes it to an array
        uni.search('.courseresult').each do |course|
            course_info = {}
            course_info[:name]          = course.search('.title').text
            course_info[:duration]      = course.search('.durationValue').text
            course_info[:qualification] = course.search('.outcomequalValue').text

            courses_array.push(course_info)
            print_course_info(course_info)
        end

        puts "--- Scraped #{courses_array.length} courses"
        return courses_array
    end





    def process_courses_page(course_page)
        courses_array = []
        page_num = 1
        next_page_link = true   
        details_link = true 
        uni_name = course_page.search('.providerinfo h3').text
        # Loops through all course pages for uni
        while next_page_link


            puts "-- Scraping #{uni_name} courses page: #{page_num}"
            # Loops through all courses and adds their info into a hash
            course_page.search('ol.resultscontainer li').each do |course|
                course_info = {}

                # Removes excess html which was interferring with text
                course.search(
                    '.courseinfoduration span, 
                     .courseinfoduration br, 
                     .courseinfooutcome span, 
                     .courseinfooutcome br').remove
                # Sets all data in hash
                course_info[:name]          = course.search('.courseTitle').text
                course_info[:duration]      = clean_text(course.search('.courseinfoduration').text)
                course_info[:qualification] = clean_text(course.search('.courseinfooutcome').text)
                # Pushes course hash to course array
                courses_array.push(course_info)
                print_course_info(course_info)


                details_link = course.search('div.coursenamearea a').first
                    if details_link
                     # If there is a link to a courses page for the uni go to that
                       course_info[:detail] = process_course_details(@mechanize.get(details_link["href"])) 

                    end
             end
                     # Checks if there is a next page and navigates to it if so
          next_page_link = course_page.search('.pager a[text()=">"]').first        
            if(next_page_link) 
                course_page = @mechanize.get(next_page_link["href"])
                page_num += 1
            end
        end
end


    def process_course_details(course_details)
        details_array =[]
        details_link = true 
        entry_link = true

                details_info = {}
                # Sets all data in hash
                details_info[:url]          = course_details.search('div.coursedetails_programmeurl a')

                details_array.push(details_info)
                print_details_info(details_info)


             entry_link = course_details.search('ul.details_tabs a').first
             if entry_link
                 details_info[:entry] = process_entry(@mechanize.get(entry_link["href"]))
             end 

     end


    def process_entry(entry_req)
        entry_array = []
        entry_link = true 

                entry_info = {}
                # Sets all data in hash
                entry_info[:req]          = entry_req.search('li.qual-element.qual_range').text.strip

                entry_array.push(entry_info)
                print_entry_info(entry_info)
    end



scraper = Scraper.new
scraper.process_unis

end


end
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Is this the minimum needed to demonstrate the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pasted a lot of code here, too much to easily read through and understand. That being said, there are a few approaches you can take to saving an array in a database.

1. Serialize it and then store it as a string. Then deserialize it when you want to read it. You might use `json` or `yaml` for this.
2. Save the data in your arrays individually. This is probably a more sensible approach because you won't have to mess with serialization. So, for example, if you have an array `fruits = ["apple", "orange"]` and `meats = ["beef", "lamb"]`, then you could make `fruits` and `meats` tables in the database, give them `name` columns, then create the appropriate entries.

Answer (score 0):

In the model you most likely want to use the serialize method. This will allow you to serialize data as arrays, hashes, json, HashieMash, etc.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a field as JSON quite easily. This is really only useful if you don't need to query the data IN the arrays. If you do have that need, you'll want to create a table to represent those arrays.

If you decide to store it as JSON it's a rather simple interface:

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4]
my_array_as_json = my_array.to_json
```

later you can get it back to an array with

```
my_array_again = JSON.parse(my_array_as_json)
```